# How to download API 15 with Google APIs for Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm on Mac, and I'm working on an Android application that targets API 15 and uses Google APIs. How can I create the appropriate virtual device? Below are the images available; is there any way to install other images?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the image below shows, system image with Google API support hadn't added until API 19.

[image]

This leaves you basically two options.

1. Use a Google API system image of recent API level and run/test your app through it. But if your app comprises of features particularly aimed for API 15 that you think you should test then this option won't work out for you.
2. People used to tinker with the emulator(created with regular system image, of course) by manually installing Google Play, Maps app via adb shell. This approach let them use a handful of Google API related stuffs(Google Map, for instance) in regular Emulator. Needless to say, with the arrival of Google API system image, this strategy has gone obsolete. But I'm sure you'll still get many resources to apply this hack on regular ARM/Intel x86 System Image based Emulator. That way you still can create a emulator of API 15 and can test Google API based few features on it.